# What does it mean by "well into the future"?

Tags: meaning

> For the novice trader, professional, or somewhere in between, these
>    books will provide the advice and strategies needed to prosper today and **well into the future**.

I know what *prosper today* means. However, I don't know what ***well into the future*** means. If I change the sentence to the following form, I'm clear of its meaning.

> ...these books will provide the advice and strategies needed to prosper today and **the future**.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: not just a little but in the future but a good way into the future.  ***well*** *a significant amount*

Answer (score 4):

"Well into the future", as opposed to just "into the future", is used to highlight the idea that this will help you in the long-term future rather than just the short-term future (and it often implies both short- *and* long-term, rather than just long-term). In your specific case it's used to stress that the books will (presumably) be setting you up for long-lasting prosperity, rather than just helping you out for a few weeks then leaving you back in financial stasis again.

In the general case, "well into" means far along or far into. From [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/well+into) (emphasis mine):

> *well into something
>
> Fig. far into something or far along in something. ... *It was **well into** the morning before she awoke. The car was **well into** the tunnel when it broke down.*

In the example sentences there, the implication is that it was late morning, or that the car was a pretty far distance into the tunnel.

For example, if you wanted to stress the idea that some financial planning will not only help you tomorrow, for the next week, or for the next year, but rather, say, all the way through your retirement years, you might say that the planning will help you "well into the future".

In "well into the future", the actual length of time is of course vague, relative and context-dependent, but it's meant to stress *long-term*.

Answer (score 2):

***Well into the future*** would imply that this knowledge you have will help you today and will continue helping you (into the future). Think of a line. It starts and continues and may eventually end. It also serves as a reassurance that this knowledge will last.

If you just said "prosper today and the future" that's two separate points in time with no guarantee of anything in between. It will help you today, and then it will help you at another point in the future. This way of speaking also doesn't reassure you when in the future. It could be 3 seconds from now, or 3 years, but it doesn't have the same feeling as "well into the future"

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the question "well into the future" means that the strategies will provide benefits for the long term and that there is also negligible risk in the short term.

The exact meaning, in general, actually depends on the motivation and honesty of whoever is making the statement.     If that person is genuinely taking a long term focus, they are providing an assurance that the benefits will continue for a significant time.    However, if that person is taking a short term focus, the same statement provides a justification for not applying the effort to monitor and see if the benefits are actually being realised in the near term.   The latter, for example, is often used by investment advisors to explain to clients why they must continue to pay commission to the advisor even in periods when their investment is making a loss.

It is sometimes quite difficult to be sure of the motivation of who is making the statement.